# How to test relative validity statistically?

Tags: regression, causality, validity

I am trying to understand a) what relative validity is, and b) how to test it statistically. So far I have gathered, from sources such as [this](http://www.psychology.uiowa.edu/faculty/wasserman/glossary/relative%20validity.html) that relative validity is a larger reliability in causation associated with certain stimuli, given a set of stimuli. It seems that some statisticians test relative validity using regression models, such as in [this article](http://journals.lww.com/lww-medicalcare/Abstract/1996/03000/A_12_Item_Short_Form_Health_Survey__Construction.3.aspx).

However, in none of these sources it is explained *how* regression (or any other statistical tool) is used to measure relative validity. Hence my question - how do you test relative validity statistically?

Comment: In response to your flag, one way to attract attention on your post is to award a bounty on it. I don't think it is necessary in this particular case. On the contrary, I think you should give more information on your particular study: The first example you provided has to do with reinforcement learning while the second is about validity of a measurement scale (and I don't really see how 'relative' applies in such circumstance). What are you interested in, and what application do you have in mind?